# Entity Framework - Assocation Question

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Let's say I have a customer with an address. Do I have to add the AddressId foreign key field to the customer or can I just add the navigation property?

Comment: much to vague to be able to answer at least tell people what version and linq to entities technology you are using

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the foreign key.

Comment: Speaking generally, this answer is wrong. However, your question is far too vague to really answer at all, so I can't fault Pedro for that.

Comment: Let's say a Story has one reviewer assigned to it and a reviewer can review multiple stories. Does my story class have to contain a reviewerid or just a navigation prop?

Comment: In this case Story should have a ReviewerId. The Reviewer class could have only a List<Story>